# get dates in range of provided start and end dates

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have records in database with start and end dates 
i want to filter out all records with are in range of start and end date

i have two query that works , gives me records between two dates and the other query gives me records that are in range of start or end date

how do i combine these two linq query into single one so it works in both ways

Linq 1

```
schedulelist = (From c In db.Table1 Where c.StartDate.Value.Date <= objStartDate.Date And c.EndDate.Value.Date >= objStartDate.Date And
c.UserID = CInt(Session("UserID"))).ToList()
```

Linq 2

```
schedulelist = (From c In db.Table1 Where (c.StartDate.Value.Date >=
objStartDate.Date And c.StartDate.Value.Date <= objEndDate.Date) Or
(c.EndDate.Value.Date >= objStartDate.Date And c.EndDate.Value.Date <=
objEndDate.Date) And c.UserID = CInt(Session("UserID"))).ToList()
```

in db table have these values

```
StartDate                EndDate  
2019-10-08 07:00:00.000  2019-10-30 07:00:00.000
2019-10-15 07:00:00.000  2019-10-27 07:00:00.000
```

if search with ObjStartDate 15/10/2019 00:00:00 and ObjEndDate 27/10/2019 00:00:00

i get record No 2 when i run Linq 2

i get Record No 1 when i run Linq 1

what i should get is both records for any Linq 1 or Linq 2

so whats the better solution to combine both into one query or this query is all wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest *query* to check if date range 1 intersects date range 2 is this:

```
... WHERE range2_end > range1_start
      AND range1_end > range2_start
```

This checks all cases such as range 1 fully inside, fully contains, starts inside or ends inside range 2.